# compare a character with double quotes " in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, string-comparison, double-quotes

I want to compare a single character with double quotes " in a  in windows batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=before
for /f %%a in (zen.csv) do (
    set var=%%a
    echo !var:~-1!
    IF "!var:~-1!"=="""" (
        @echo found
    )
)
pause
```

the result is like:

```
０
１
"
"
"
０
１
２
```

As you can see, the batch did not output the "found". How to compare a character with double quotes?

Comment: Have you tried with \" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=before
for /f %%a in (zen.csv) do (
    set var=%%a
    echo !var:~-1!
    IF !var:~-1!==^" (
        @echo found
    )
)
pause
```

Escape a double quote with a caret `^` to become `^"`. Omit the outer double quotes for the comparison. The caret will escape many characters except for `%` which needs to be escaped by doubling up to become `%%`.